# Creating CMS endpoints for verification PublishThis

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke, publishing

We have a dotnetnuke website, wherein we need to implement PublishThis, now as i went through the site, i came to know it just have supports for (wordpress and drupal) for other CMS'es they have an API, which can be consumed and pull respective content from PublishThis and store it in our database.

They have mentioned about CMS EndPoints on their site, but it's not clear how we can create a CMS Endpoints, so that PublishThis can verify us, there are no examples of doing the same, when i tried to create new cms and added my website url as a Client, it threw below error:

```
Oops. Your CMS could not be verified. Error message: The endpoint is not returning JSON but text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Can anyone tell me how should i create a CMS EndPoints for PublishThis.

Answer (score 0):

This page describes CMS endpoint setup.

http://docs.publishthis.com/edcenter/developers-and-admins/setting-up-a-cms-publishing-option/implementing-your-cms-endpoint-actions/

First of all you need to ensure that your server returns MIME type 'application/json'. Then you need to return correct response that depends on your specific query and is described in documentation.